# Properly placing user controls on FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm working in a WinForms C# .NET 3.5 desktop software.

I'm trying to add a `UserControl` consists only a `GroupBox` in a `FlowLayoutPanel`. When I try the following code:

```
GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();

flowLayoutPanelConfig.Controls.Add(gb);
flowLayoutPanelConfig.SetFlowBreak(gb, true);
```

the `GroupBox` is shown beautifully:

[image]

But when I try to put the `GroupBox` in a `UserControl`:

```
GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
UserControl uc = new UserControl();
uc.Controls.Add(gb);

flowLayoutPanelConfig.Controls.Add(uc);
flowLayoutPanelConfig.SetFlowBreak(uc, true);
```

and try to show the UserControl, the GroupBox breaks:

[image]

Why is that?

This is a test code. I've a user control in some separate files which I need to add in a `FlowLayoutPanel`. That also breaks this way.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a more realistic example is needed. It really depends on whether the `UserControl` is predesigned, hence has a correct size set in the design time, in which case it will show correctly. The problem in the runtime example you've shown is that the user control has default size which is different from the group box size, hence is clipping the child group box.

If you want to avoid the clipping and use the group box size, you should set [`UserControl.AutoSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true` and [`UserControl.AutoSizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.autosizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink`:

```
GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
UserControl uc = new UserControl();
uc.AutoSize = true;
uc.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
uc.Controls.Add(gb);

flowLayoutPanelConfig.Controls.Add(uc);
flowLayoutPanelConfig.SetFlowBreak(uc, true);
```